# C++ odd compile error: error: changes meaning of "Object" from class "Object"

Tags: c++, xcode

I don't even know where to go with this. Google wasn't very helpful. As with my previous question. I'm using TextMate's Command+R to compile the project.

> game.h:16:error: declaration of ‘Player* HalfSet::Player() const’
>
> players.h:11:error: changes meaning of ‘Player’ from ‘class Player’
>
> game.h:21:error: ‘Player’ is not a type

player.h file (partial)

```
#ifndef PLAYERS_H
#define PLAYERS_H
using namespace std;

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "generics.h"

class Player{ //Line 11
public:
    //getters
    long Id() const;
    string FirstName() const;
    string LastName() const;
    string Country() const;
    //setters
    void setId(long id);
    void setFirstName(string s);
    void setLastName(string s);
    void setCountry(string s);
    //serializing functions
    void display(ostream &out);
    void read(istream &in);
    void write(ostream &out);
    //Initalizers
    Player();
    Player(istream &in);
    Player(string firstName, string lastName);
    Player(string firstName, string lastName, string country);
    Player(long id, string firstName, string lastName, string country);
    ~Player();
private:
    long _id;
    string _firstName;
    string _lastName;
    string _country;
};
```

game.h file (partial)

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "generics.h"
#include "players.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class HalfSet{
public:
    //getters
    Player* Player() const; //Line 16
    int GamesWon() const;
    int TotalPoints() const;
    int Errors() const;
    //setters
    void setPlayer(Player* p);
    void setGamesWon(int games);
    void setTotalPoints(int points);
    void setErrors(int errors);
    //Serialization
    void display(ostream &out) const;
    void read(istream &in) const;
    void write(ostream &out) const;
    //Initalizers
    HalfSet();
    ~HalfSet();
private:
    Player* _player;
    int _gamesWon;
    int _points;
    int _errors;
};
```

What is going on here?

Comment: The current accepted answer to this question is just incorrect as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C++ you cannot name a function the same name as a class/struct/typedef.  You have a class named "Player" and so the HalfSet class has a function named "Player" ("Player *Player()").  You need to rename one of these (probably changing HalfSet's Player() to getPlayer() or somesuch).

Comment: Well - you can, but not a member function.

Comment: Doing ::Player *Player() for line 16 would fix this issue.  (as suggested b @MSalters)

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual C++ compiler lets you do this, so you get a nasty surprise if when trying to compile with g++ something which is working on windows.

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is that names are looked up in scopes. Within the declaration of `HalfSet::setPlayer(Player*)`, the unqualified name `Player` needs to be looked up. The first scope tried is `class HalfSet`. In that scope, the lookup of `Player` finds function `HalfSet::Player`, not `global class ::Player`.

The solution is to use a qualified name, `::Player`. This tells the compiler which scope to use for lookup (global) which in turn means `HalfSet::Player` is not even considered.

Answer (score 10):

The current answer to this question is just incorrect, it says:

> In C++ you cannot name a function the same name as a class/struct/typedef

Name hiding of a class by a function is allowed, if we go to the [draft Pre C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1804.pdf) section `3.3.7` *Name hiding* it says:

> A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name
>   of an object, function, or enumerator declared in the same scope. If a
>   class or enumeration name and an object, function, or enumerator are
>   declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the
>   class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the object, function, or
>   enumerator name is visible.

So the fact that you have the function and a class named `Player` is not the issue, in fact the following code is valid:

```
class Player
{
} ;

Player* Player() ;
```

and we can use an [elaborated type specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902518/when-to-use-an-elaborated-type-specifier) to un-hide the class type.

As far as I can tell this is violating section `3.3.6` *Class scope* paragraph `2` which says:

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its
>   context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No
>   diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

So in this case `Player` changes meaning from *class* to a *function*, it is not clear to me it was intended so strictly but I can see how it could be read that way. This seems to be the message `gcc` uses when it detects this violation as we can see from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26681873/1708801).

Using an elaborated type specifier prevents the change of meaning:

```
class Player* Player() const ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on my code I can't comprehend this

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

But this what I did so it fixed my error

previous code

```
#include "a.h"

class System {
 public:
  car car;    /*This line is problem, Can't declare object with same name as 
               class*/
};
```

Modified code

```
#include "a.h"

 class System {
  public:
   car Car;      //Here is the difference, Just changed first letter of object
  };
```